# Is my proof of commutativity of multiplication correct (Peano's axioms Proof)

Tags: real-analysis, foundations

Prove that a x m = m x a for natural numbers a and m.

LEMMAS:

1. $n+0=n$
2. $n+m++=(n+m)++$
3. $a++=a +1$ (True since $a++$ is counting forward one step)
4. Addition is commutative

By induction
Base step:
Let m be an arbitrary natural number, and a be 0. Then by definition a x m =0. Since m is a natural number, then m is obtained by counting forward from 0. Hence a x m becomes a x (n0++) = a x n0 (by lemma 1), which can be represented as a x (n1++) = a x n1  and so on until 0 x m=0. We know that this can be done since a is obtained by counting forward from 0. Hence m x a =0= a x m.
Inductive step:
Assume a x m= m x a. Then a++ x m is (a x m) + m = (m x a)+m = m+ (m x a). We can constantly count backwards instead of forwards, shifting “a”s from m x a to m. Since a is natural and can be obtained from counting forwards by 1 , similarly, 0 can be obtained by counting backwards from a by repeatedly deducting 1. We eventually obtain (1+a) x m  +0 = (a++) x m.

Comment: In most cases, if you're working with Peano's axioms, you shouldn't be saying things like "$0$ can be obtained by counting backwards from $a$" or "we eventually obtain". These can always be substituted by a proper proof by induction. The point of Peano arithmetic is kind of to let go of intuitive reasoning about natural numbers, and use very very rigorous reasoning instead.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Use [Peano's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic). If so, you have the axiom $(m \times 0)=0$ and thus you **have to prove** that $(0 \times m)=0$.